# SQL Issue with retrieving a particular row

Tags: php, sql

I have a question about my sql query which seems to be playing up.

I am fully prepared to admit any fault in the code i am using but i cannot foe the life of me work out what is happening

Below is my table:

```
id    groupingid    groupid    timeadded
------------------------------------------
1     1              4         1318200332
2     2              2         1318200346
3     3              1         1318200362
4     4              3         1318200388
5     5              6         1318217398
6     7              7         1318217402
7     8              8         1318217408
8     6              5         1318217413
9     9              9         1318217417
10    5              7         1319007223
65    14             14        1319068963
64    11             15        1319068950
62    10             15        1319068921
63    13             14        1319068950
61    12             14        1319068887
60    11             14        1319068850
59    10             14        1319068847
70    12             15        1319069000
```

All I am wanting to do is return any row with a 'groupid' of 15 and then isolate the row with the highest 'groupingid'

therefore i am using the following sql_query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mdl_groupings_groups` 
WHERE groupid = 15 
ORDER BY MAX('groupingid')
```

It keeps returning:

```
id  groupingid      groupid timeadded
------------------------------------------
64  11              15      1319068950
```

whereas it should be returning the row with the id of 70

Please tell me what COMPLETELY OBVIOUS thing i am missing as i am on a tight deadline and have no idea what is wrong here.

My apologies if this is not formatted correctly and flame away if needed..

Thanks

Comment: "Flaming" on SO is not really very well received. You should (hopefully) experience more professional responses, although there are some rogues who cause disruption. Just please remember to upvote good answers and mark an appropriate answer for your questions when possible. `:)`

Comment: thanks :) I expect people to be respectful but know that i will not always receive it... figure if i add it in there people will go easy on me ;)

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

- Use `ORDER BY ... DESC` instead of `ORDER BY MAX(...)`
- Don't put the column name `groupingid` in single quotes.

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_groupings_groups
WHERE groupid = 15
ORDER BY groupingid DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from mdl_groupings_group
WHERE groupingID IN 
(
SELECT max(groupingID) as TheMax
FROM `mdl_groupings_groups` 
WHERE groupid = 15 
) xx
ORDER BY groupingID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This will return two rows: id 61 and 70.

Comment: Thanks, tweaked the query just for completeness

Comment: Excellent! Worked great, thanks to you both for your prompt replies... much appreciated

Comment: Just out of interest and to learn, is MAX not an accurate way of retrieving the biggest Number in a table (like what i was trying to achieve)?